# Spring Data for MongoDB: check if one of the keys exist in the Map<String, Integer>

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a document which holds a `Map` of `<String, Integer>`.

Given a `Set<String>`, I'd like to query all documents such that *at least one* of the strings in the given set, exists as key of the map.

i.e. if the map is `{"foo" : 1, "baz": 2}` and the given set is `"["foo"]` this specific document will be retrieved.

Other formulation of the query: the intersection between the map's keyset and the given set isn't the empty set.

I thought the easy way doing that is using having multiple `Criteria`s of the form

`Criteria.where("path.to.map." + key).exists(true);`

And chaining them using: `criteria.orOperator()`, but `orOperator` doesn't accept a collection.

What's the proper way doing that?